# Why was Christian Gedges' post deleted by Caleb 7 hours ago?

Tags: discussion

[Is Paul's visit to Jerusalem detailed in Galatians 2 the Jerusalem Council?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-pauls-visit-to-jerusalem-detailed-in-galatians-2-the-jerusalem-council)

It has no votes, adds to the resolution of the question and posed no threat to national security.

Are mods supposed to just go around and delete posts they don't happen to like or agree with?

And the worst part is that it doesn't even show up in a search.

Caleb? How is this your place as a moderator? Can you PLEASE stop doing this. I don't believe your assurances that you won't be deleting my posts when I turn my back because you turn around again and again to delete stuff you should not even be permitted to do. PLEASE STOP DOING THIS. NOW AND FOR GOOD.

Comment: Any constructive discussion here must start with mutual respect including assuming good intentions and not shouting in all caps. There is also a scoping issue. Do you want to talk about the particular post you linked, a general problem you witness, or a potential problem you do not witness (yet)?

Comment: @Keelan  Are you a moderator?

Comment: My guess is that someone flagged the post as NAA (not an answer). I'm the only person who *upvoted* the post so I guess it matters that even I don't think it answers the question. It's a moderator's main job to respond to flags — and that includes deleting non-answers.

Comment: "Not an answer" is not a reason to delete a post. The burden is that it must contribute to the answer. Hover your mouse over the up button and see what I mean. And the site is supposed to be self-curated by the voting system, not by the whims of a single rogue moderator. The man had NO down votes and provided a very helpful chart (regardless of whether you agree with it). All this "Not an answer" mess has made this site pretty much unbearable. You don't have to put up with this subterfuge on Quora.

Comment: @JackDouglas If you upvoted an A that in your judgement "doesn't answer the Q", then *that* is some strange behaviour? I haven't read it and cannot see it now, but why upvote – and why does Ruminator say it had "no votes"?

Comment: As a moderator on a different SE site I can tell you that NAA definitely is a reason to delete a post.

Comment: @LangLangC The answer post in reference here had +1/-1 votes at the time of deletion, for a sum total score of 0. The OP here has a history of playing a bit fast and loose in his descriptions of activity on the site when the actual tooling and usage history don't fit his narrative. In this case it doesn't really matter, even if the post had been heavily upvoted (as tangential posts often are) it was still NAA. The same often happens with questions: off topic, too broad, and opinion based questions are often popular and attract upvotes. That doesn't make it invalid to close them.

Comment: @LangLangC I upvoted the answer because I personally found it useful — I should probably have also flagged it NAA because it isn't an answer to the question. I don't see any contradiction between liking something and finding it useful while also recognizing that it is out of place!

Comment: Ruminator, you say "'Not an answer' is not a reason to delete a post", but you couldn't be more wrong. You only have to press the 'flag' link on any answer to see that the intention is to convert or simply delete non-answers, even if they are useful.

Comment: @JackDouglas Seems quite contradictory to me. If you liked it and found it useful enough to UV, it *must* have been an answer – even if only tangentially contributing – in your eyes? But as I haven't seen the root of this dispute, and cannot have an opinion on the answer-post's quality, I'll stop wondering about this now. Everyone can vote as they like.

Comment: Rules that are applied willy-nilly are not rules, just control tools. I guess we can't walk together if posts with no net down votes are deleted from time to time, in secret, this will not work for me at all.

Comment: @LangLangC I don't only find on topic answers useful — but I do want the site to flourish and that means removing posts that don't answer the question whether I find them useful or not. That's partly why we aren't just another discussion forum.

Answer (score 7):

### The post does not answer the question.

As a matter of fact, it doesn't even claim to answer the question, it even clams to "go beyond the scope of the question" and offer a "supporting diagram to the question". It does not postulate an answer to the question that was asked.

The post was not inherently "bad content" or anything like that. If this was a discussion forum it would have been a perfectly acceptable post on the thread. **But this is not a discussion forum and you should not expect posts to be treated like replies would be in a forum thread.**

## It *is* the job of moderators to remove posts that are not answers.

As a matter of fact, this job falls to more than just moderators. All site users have access to a link to flag posts as "Not An Answer", and all high-rep site users are shown such flagged posts in a review queue and have the ability to vote to delete such posts.

The only thing special about moderators is that our votes on those actions (such as Vote-To-Delete) are binding. It takes a couple separate users voting to delete to actually remove a post, one moderator can speed the operation along with a binding vote.

The help section spells out the details. of [user and moderator action types](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/reputation) and specifically about [post deletion](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

### The post was flagged as NAA (Not An Answer).

- ...by a user other than myself.
- I agreed with the assessment.
- ...and acted accordingly.
- Since then a [third voice](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3616/why-was-christian-gedges-post-deleted-by-caleb-7-hours-ago#comment6164_3616) has agreed it was NAA.

The post was deleted fully in accordance with this site's *modus operandi* and I believe I'm doing my job as a moderator.

### What you should do...

If you (or anyone else) see content posted as an answer that does not directly answer the original question you should ⓐ flag it as NAA and ⓑ vote to delete if you have that option and ⓒ if there is content that *adds value* in the way of background information to the question or other answers, that information can be edited into the respective posts. If it helps frame the question better, edit it into the question. If it helps support another answer, edit it into that answer.

1. Expect answer posts to answer the question.
2. Expect non-answer posts to be removed.
3. Use the site tools accordingly.

Comment: Well, this seems to answer the question from OP. And I can agree. But isn't it a bit incomplete? Errors as well as disagreements might occur. If there is an argument about the validity of deletion, then I thought very hi-rep users might undelete, all might flag it for undeletion and when that flag is declined take it to meta (which might have been, but apparently isn't the step/case here), finally appeal to 'SE community team'. Then, or at any time along the ladder, it might be time to accept that and move on. If I am not completely wrong, that is.

Comment: @LangLangC Of course this is incomplete if you're looking for start-to-finish guide for how deletions would normally be handled. But that's all in help and we've been over it on meta many times. If he had asked about the general procedure to contest a deletion, the answer would be ① flag for a second review ② make a case for reversal on meta, ③ if mods ignore community demand on meta, take it to community team. But that wasn't the question asked. This is my response to what was actually asked, which is basically a rant about how mods should never delete any posts. I explain why they should.

Comment: The hypocrisy here of "adherence to policy" is a joke. For example, a popular question right now is "What is the gospel of the NT?" If I had asked that I would have been stoned. But, people like the question even though it is a theological and not an exegetical question. Total hypocrisy:  5 upvotes and zero votes to close/migrate. And so on and so on. It is selective application of the "rules". But if you look at the upvote button it says "this answer is useful". And the chart the gentleman provided was in fact a graphical answer. The answer was short but the graphic was worth a 1000 words.

Comment: But for me, I consider it foolish to keep putting my pearls in a bag with holes in it. There are other sites don't play these political games and posts are not deleted willy-nilly.

Comment: @Ruminator That other question is a good example of something that's popular but not good for the site. See my comments of a couple days ago when people started flagging it because they couldn't VtC while the bounty is active. We'll take care of it in time. In the meanwhile… **You're right. There are plenty of forums out there that never delete anything and only allow upvotes not down.** Feel free to use them. This site offers something else. I have an idea you keep coming back because you feel the effect of our higher signal-to-noise ratio even though you protest so vigorously at our methods.

Comment: I know what is valuable here. It is not the vigorousness of your methods but the fact that they are applied inconsistently with large offenders being treated with Trumpian immunity while others, like this gentleman's helpful post are deleted because "rules are rules". I wanted to upvote the answer. But the unforgivable sin is that my posts are liable to deletion behind the scenes. Not gonna continue. Bye.

Comment: @Caleb  So you are going to let everyone invest their time providing answers and then delete it all??? Double Bye.